# PHP Defining Function Logical

Tags: php

I am just starting out learning php, and I was wondering someone can help me out with the logical of defining functions.  I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Simple Example:

```
<?php

function hello($word) {
  echo "Hello $word";
}

  $name = "John";
  strtolower(hello($name))

?>
```

I know if I use return instead of echo in the function and then echo it outside defining the function, the "strtolower" applies, but in this example it doesn't.  I don't get how php is interpreting it.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Imagine a function is a box of unknown content. You put something in and something comes out - meaning you have *parameters* and something to be *returned*.

In your code example you don't return anything, instead `echo` some string.

```
function hello($word) {
//             ^ parameter
  return "Hello $word";
}

$name = "John";
strtolower(hello($name));
```

---

To explain a bit further, you can look at your original code this way:

```
echo strtolower(hello("John"));
     ^          ^--- call hello("John")
     |                something happens (your echo)
     |               hello() ended without return, return NULL by default
     |--- call strtolower( NULL )
            something happens
          strtolower() returned ""
```

But you want it to be like this:

```
echo strtolower(hello("John"));
     ^          ^--- call hello("John")
     |                something happens
     |               hello() return "Hello John"
     |--- call strtolower("Hello John")
            something happens
          strtolower() returned "hello john"
```

Comment: @JohnConde Finally - Ha, tonight I shall feast!

Comment: Seems that people like stories like this `box of unknown content` story. Thus voting up :)

Comment: But the thing is that the original code doesn't return " ".  It returns "Hello John"  When the function is called, it still returns the echo the only thing is that the strtolower doesn't apply.

Comment: @user3428247 No! `Hello John` gets printed to the screen (because you used `echo`), but if you use sth like output buffer or just do `var_dump( strtolower( hello($word) ) );` (instead of `echo`), you'll see that the function returns `NULL`